# Enumeration in Codeigniter: Undefined property: ProjectStatus_Enum::$Open

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I created a class in Library Folder.

```
class ProjectStatus_Enum {

    const Open          =   1;
    const InProgress    =   2;
}
```

and below is the code in Controller.

```
class ProjectController extends MY_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library("ProjectStatus_Enum");
        echo $this->projectstatus_enum->Open;
    }
}
```

when this line executes...`echo $this->projectstatus_enum->Open;` I am getting below error..

> Undefined property: ProjectStatus_Enum::$Open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sample class in Library Folder.**

```
class ProjectStatus_Enum {

    const Open          =   1;
    const InProgress    =   2;
}
```

**Class variable will not be accessible directly.**

```
class ProjectController extends MY_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library("ProjectStatus_Enum");
        $ProjectStatus = $this->projectstatus_enum;//=> Direct variable call will not work
        echo $ProjectStatus::Open;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to the :: for constants (const) and -> for class properties. So in your case use

```
echo $this->projectstatus_enum::Open;
```

or

```
echo ProjectStatus_Enum::Open
```

Comment: You are missing few things. I just got the code working. Please check my post and Many thanks for the help.

Comment: Ah, yes it was not meant as a fully working example, more a push in the right direction, good that you got it working!